# How to do the proper login in a website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am a new bee creating an asp.net web application for my application. I will have different users and i didn't use any special forms or methods to do the login. I have access db , in there i have some user role, company,username , and password.
In my login page through text box i will get company username and password inputting by the end user. then i will check for the company and username (which is primary key in the table.) if the password matches then will find the user role and redirect to the pages for each user.
that works fine now.
I have a log out button which is sitting in the sitemaster page and

```
      <div id="logout" runat="server" visible="false" class="navbar-brand1">  
                  <a id="lo"  runat="server" href="/Default">Log Out </a>
            </div>
```

then in the pages where i want to show the log out i will call the code

```
    Master.FindControl("logout").Visible = true;
```

it was working fine in respect of login in and login out . but infact the log out button just redirects to the first page on site and if we do the back arrow in the browser i can go back to the prevs page i was on. Is there any way i can do it neatly so that after log out even though if i go back on the browser it will ask for log in .

Any help will be really appreciated. I made a mistake and created complete application now i am worried about this feature so technically i am not logging out  :(

Comment: When the user login, set the username to a session variable.                         Also, when the user opens each and every page in the system, check if that session variable is empty or not.                                                              If empty, redirect to LogIn page.                                                                  when the user log out clear the session.

Comment: It seems good approach. Can you please provide me some code as well.Many thanks

Comment: Answer is provided below with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a user opens a page in the system use below code to check if the session is valid

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]).Length <= 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }
```

When the user clicks on SignOut button, make redirection to a SignOut.aspx page. Use below code in the form load event of SignOut.aspx to clear the session.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();

    Session.Contents.RemoveAll();

    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the session["username"] value? so it always go to login page by redirection i guess?

Comment: You have to set it in the Login page. Yes when the user signout it will go to signout.aspx page first and from there it will redirect to Login page.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chathuranga Ranasinghe mentioned I used session varibale to store the username details and i will check if the session variable empty then go to my default page otherwise continue.

```
   if (((string)Session["iden"]) )
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
        }
```

i used this on the pages comes after logged in and it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is how to do the

> proper login

The proper way is not to reinvent the wheel, but use the framework that is built in in ASP.NET

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It will give you a lot of extra features, like using OpenAuth etc.

Example
"https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354509%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I know there are other ways to do it, BUt i mentioned that i already completed the aplication i cannot work more on it .so just adjust the settings to save the data from website .